# ReportViewer styling

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, reportviewer, styling

With the ReportViewer control, is it possible to apply predefined style (from css) across multiple reports?

For example, I would like anchor links to look the same across different reports on different pages. Specifying their cssClass property doesn't seem to work because peeking into the generated html, the inline style (which is so bulky that my heart bled a little from the inside) is overriding those from style sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also would like this. Did you find out?

Comment: More or less. I found out I didn't need it as bad as I did. But the solution was to give the reportviewer a class, and define all its children styles through group selector like so: 

.MyReportViewerClass td{ background-color:red}